# Port and IP address usage in UDP communication

Tags: c++, udp, ports

I have two clients and I want to connect them to daemon which is using UDP socket. It is using IP addr1 and Port#1 for communication. In each client, I create a socket with the same IP and port#1 that daemon is using. Is that okay to use same IP address and port# for both clients?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what you mean by "use."

It is correct for both clients to do `connect()` or `sendto()` using the IP and port the daemon is listening on.

It would not be ok for any of the clients to do `bind()` using the IP and port the daemon is listening on.

Comment: I want to use sendto() and recv() methods in order to sent and receive data. When will I use bind()? What is it used for?

Comment: `bind()` is only used when you want control of the source IP and/or port your client is going to use. When you call `sendto()` on an UDP socket the operating system will perform an implicit `bind()` for you, so normally a client don't need to call `bind()`.